# How to determine the number of array 100 are not equal to each other

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I am coding a Sudoku program. I found the number in the array determine whether duplicate each other is hard.

Now I have an array: `int streamNum[SIZE]`

- if SIZE=3,I can handle this problem like:`if(streamNum[0]!=streamNum[1])...`
- if SIZE=100,I think that I need a better solution, is there any standard practice?

Comment: Post your code. It may help others to answer.

Comment: Pick a language. It will likely significantly change the answers you get. Doing this in C++ will likely be markedly different than C.

Comment: Just for clarity: Are we to assume this is a *fully-populated* sequence? I.e, are you testing *partial* rows/columns as well (ones that have not been fully populated yet)? If so, is your "empty" determination some sentinel value such as zero (`0`) and said-sentinel should therefore be ignored when deducing unique-value distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, I suppose the easiest is to write two loops

```
bool has_duplicate = false;
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE && !has_duplicate; ++i)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < SIZE && !has_duplicate; ++j)
        if (streamNum[i] == streamNum[j])
            has_duplicate = true;
if (has_duplicate)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    ...
}
```

The first loop goes through each element in the array, the second loop checks if there is a duplicate in the remaining elements of the array (that's why it starts at `i + 1`). Both loops quit as soon as you find a duplicate (that's what `&& !has_duplicate` does).

This is not the most efficient way, more efficient would be to sort the array before looking for duplicates but that would modify the contents of the array at the same time.

I hope I've understand your requirements well enough.

Comment: seems like a bubble-sort,nice job

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    for(int j=i+1;j<size;j++){
        if(streamNUM[i]==streamNUM[j]){
           ...........
        }
     }
}
```

I assume that u need whether there is duplication or not this may be helpful

If not comment

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what exactly you're looking to do here but I'm assuming as it's sudoku you're only interested in storing numbers 1-9?

If so to test for a duplicate you could iterate through the source array and use a second array (with 9 elements - I've called it flag) to hold a flag showing whether each number has been used or not.

So.. something like:

```
for (loop=0;loop<size;loop++) {
    if (flag[streamNum[loop]]==true) {
        //duplicate - do something & break this loop
        break;
    }
    else {
       flag[streamNum[loop]=true;
    }
}
```

Here's how I'd test against Sudoku rules - it checks horizontal, vertical and 3x3 block using the idea above but here 3 different flag arrays for the 3 rules.  This assumes your standard grid is held in an 81-element array.  You can easily adapt this to cater for partially-completed grids..

```
for (loop=0;loop<9;loop++) {
    flagH=[];
    flagV=[];
    flagS=[];

    for (loop2=0;loop2<9;loop2++) {
        //horizontal
        if(flagH[streamNum[(loop*9)+loop2]]==true) {
           duplicate
        else {
           flagH[streamNum[(loop*9)+loop2]]=true);
        }

        //column test
        if(flagV[streamNum[loop+(loop2*9)]]==true) {
        ..same idea as above

        //3x3 sub section test
        basecell = (loop%3)*3+Math.floor(loop/3)*27; //topleft corner of 3x3 square
        cell = basecell+(loop2%3+(Math.floor(loop2/3)*9));
        if(flagS[streamNum[cell]]==true) {
        ..same idea as before..

   }
}
```